# UWP img in notification from base64 string

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

when I create a notification in uwp app, and I try set the image, it does work when I do something like:

```
((XmlElement)imageAttribute[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/Test.png");
```

This works fine. But what I need is to set the image from base64 string and not from the Assets folder. Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Could you show more about that how do you set the image from `base64` string?

Comment: I try do something like `((XmlElement)imageAttribute[0]).SetAttribute("src", "data:image/png;base64,(my base64 img)");`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read a string and have it work as binary data. You need to first read the base64 string and convert it back to binary which would be usually in a type of byte array or something.

after you read the base64 string and convert it back to the binary data, then you can use that instead of the binary file in your attribute instead of referencing a resource.

There are multiple sources out there for converting base64 to binary data and/or files so an internet search should yield the results you are looking for... without knowing anything about the language you are writing in, it is impossible to give examples here but the method is the same.

Comment: Please be more specific with your answer. Provide a reference to where the resources can be found. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.